# Auto run JS getter function

Tags: javascript

I have code simplified below:

```
function ValueTime(birthDate, presentValue, maxMonths = 1200){
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.presentValue = presentValue;
    this.maxMonths = maxMonths;
    this.maxYears = 0;

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        "calcValue": {
            "get": function(){
                this.maxYears = this.maxMonths/12;
                return this.presentValue * 1.25;
            }
        }
    });

}

const myVariable = new ValueTime(new Date(1985,06,23),1000);

console.log(myVariable);
console.log(myVariable.calcValue);
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
```

If I run myVariable.calcValue first like the example I get the maxYears set correctly. Is there a way to get the maxYears correctly without initiating the get function manually (`myVariable.calcValue`). I.e. get the get function to run automatically. Don't worry about the value of maxYears, I know it is simple to set otherwise but the actual code is much more complex. My quastion is about running the getter on initializing of the constructor function.

Comment: You typically really don't want getters to mutate state that's really confusing to people reading/using your code.

Comment: I get what the other two answers is getting at. It is not about the actual maxYears value. In the actual code the getter returns an array of objects based on thousands of calculations. The maxYears is a running total and I am trying to avoid having to do the calculations twice to set each return.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `calcValue` from your constructor function:

```js
function ValueTime(birthDate, presentValue, maxMonths = 1200) {
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
  this.presentValue = presentValue;
  this.maxMonths = maxMonths;
  this.maxYears = 0;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    "calcValue": {
      "get": function() {
        this.maxYears = this.maxMonths / 12;
        return this.presentValue * 1.25;
      }
    }
  });
  
  console.log(this.calcValue); // Or this.maxYears, etc.
}

const myVariable = new ValueTime(new Date(1985, 06, 23), 1000);
```

Comment: I get what the other two answers is getting at. It is not about the actual maxYears value. In the actual code the getter returns an array of objects based on thousands of calculations. The maxYears is a running total and I am trying to avoid having to do the calculations twice to set each return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why `calcValue`, which is a getter, also calculates and sets the value of `maxYears`. It seems like you want `maxYears` to be its own computed property.

```js
function ValueTime(birthDate, presentValue, maxMonths = 1200){
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.presentValue = presentValue;
    this.maxMonths = maxMonths;

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        maxYears: {
            // Add `enumerable: true` if you want to make the property show
            // up when iterating the object properties. eg. `Object.keys(obj)`
            // or `for (const key in obj)`, etc.
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () { return this.maxMonths / 12 },
            set: function (maxYears) { this.maxMonths = maxYears * 12 },
        },
        calcValue: {
            get: function () { return this.presentValue * 1.25 },
            set: function (calcValue) { this.presentValue = calcValue / 1.25 },
        },
    });
}

const myVariable = new ValueTime(new Date(1985,06,23),1000);

console.log(myVariable);
console.log(myVariable.maxMonths);
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
myVariable.maxYears = 42;
console.log(myVariable.maxMonths);
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
console.log(myVariable.calcValue);
```

If you are looking for a way to just set `maxYears` without being recalculated. You could do so by moving `this.maxMonths = maxYears * 12` into the constructor, omitting the whole getter/setter for it. However when you do this and `maxMonths` changes, `maxYears` will not be automatically updated.

---

Based on your comment it seems like your question is not really what you asked, but more in the vein of "How can I avoid re-calculation of a getter return value?".

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

1. Calculate the value on initialization. Then update it accordingly when methods are called that would effect the value.
2. Instead of keeping track of the calculated value, you could also opt to calculate it when you need it. Then if called again with the same arguments (dependencies) return the previously calculated value. Only re-calculate when one of the arguments changes.

There are probably more ways to avoid re-calculation of the value, but these are the two that come to mind. I've worked out an example of the second method below.

```js
const memorize = (() => {
  const eqArray = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((_, i) => a[i] === b[i]);
  return (fn) => {
    let result, prevArgs;
    return (...args) => {
      if (!prevArgs || !eqArray(args, prevArgs)) {
        prevArgs = args;
        result   = fn(...args);
      }
      return result;
    };
  };
})();

// demo
const add = memorize((a, b) => {
  console.log("calculate", a, "+", b);
  return a + b;
});

console.log("--- demonstration ---");
console.log("first call (calculate)");
console.log(add(1, 2));
console.log("second call with same arguments (memorized)");
console.log(add(1, 2));
console.log("third call with new arguments (re-calculate)");
console.log(add(2, 3));

// applied to question scenario
function ValueTime(birthDate, presentValue, maxMonths = 1200) {
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
  this.presentValue = presentValue;
  this.maxMonths = maxMonths;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    maxYears: {
      get: (() => {
        const calcMaxYears = memorize((maxMonths) => {
          console.log("calculate maxYears");
          // simulate heavy workload
          const until = Date.now() + 2000;
          while (Date.now() < until);
          return maxMonths / 12;
        });
        return function () { return calcMaxYears(this.maxMonths) };
      })(),
    }
  });
}

const myVariable = new ValueTime(new Date(1985,06,23),1000);

console.log("--- applied to your scenario ---");
console.log("first maxYears call (calculate)");
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
console.log("second maxYears call (memorized)");
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
myVariable.maxMonths = 504;
console.log("first maxYears call re-assigning maxMonths (re-calculate)");
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
console.log("second maxYears call after re-assigning maxMonths (memorized)");
console.log(myVariable.maxYears);
```

```html
Check your browswer console for output (re-run snippet). The output
below only shows when the JavaScript completely finishes exectuting.
```

Note that equality is checked with the `===` operator. Which means that you must not mutate the objects passed as arguments. Since the references are compared they will be considered as the same value if you do.

```
const add = memorize((a, b) => a.value + b.value);
const a = { value: 1 };
const b = { value: 2 };
console.log(add(a, b)); // logs 3
a.value = 5; // modify the value (object reference stays the same)
console.log(add(a, b)); // logs 3
const c = { value: 5 };
console.log(add(c, b)); // logs 7
```

Comment: I get what the other two answers is getting at. It is not about the actual maxYears value. In the actual code the getter returns an array of objects based on thousands of calculations. The maxYears is a running total and I am trying to avoid having to do the calculations twice to set each return.

Comment: @RussellTemplar I updated my answer, but as it stands the second part does not fit the initially asked question. Even if this does solve your problem.